# Evaluate the following limit; L'Hospital

Tags: limits, derivatives

$\ \frac{lim}{x \rightarrow 0} (\frac{1}{3x} - \frac{1}{e^{3x} -1})$

I know I am suppose to use L'Hospital but it hasn't worked for me yet. I thought at first it was DNE because I had $\frac{1}{3x^2}$ for my first term. But that and both negative and positive infinity failed.

Comment: Hint: try writing it as a single fraction

Comment: It's the same as the limit of $1/x-1/(e^x-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to combine the fractions first.
$$\lambda=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{3x}-\frac{1}{e^{3x}-1}\right)$$
$$\lambda=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{3x}-1-3x}{3x(e^{3x}-1)}\right)\stackrel{\mathcal{H^2}}{=}\dfrac{1}{2}$$
Where $\mathcal{H^2}$ denotes the application of L'Hopital's rule twice.

Comment: This is wrong as the answer is $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

I combined the fractions
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\Biggl(\frac{e^{3x}-1-3x}{3x(e^{3x}-1)}\Biggr)$$
Then I applied L'Hospital rule twice
$$\Biggl(\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(e^{3x}-1-3x)}{\frac{d}{dx}(3x(e^{3x}-1))}\Biggr)$$
$$\Biggl(\frac{3(e^{3x}-1)}{e^{3x}(9x+3)-3}\Biggr)$$
$$\Biggl(\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(3(e^{3x}-1))}{\frac{d}{dx}(e^{3x}(9x+3)-3)}\Biggr)$$
$$\Biggl(\frac{9e^{3x}}{9e^{3x}(3x+2)}\Biggr)$$
Now I could plug in zero in to x to get
$$\frac{9}{18}$$
Thus the limit equals 
$$\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$=\lim_{3x\to0}\dfrac{e^{3x}-1-3x}{(3x)^2}\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{3x}-1}{3x}}$$

If we want to avoid  [L'Hôpital Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) or [Series Expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html),

use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion) for the first limit

Comment: You are implicitly using the expansion $e^x = 1+x+x^2/2+O(x^3)$.

Comment: @martycohen, Are you talking about $L4$ of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion